# Google Form responses to multiple spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to have certain columns of the original spreadsheet created from forms responses to be copied into other spreadsheets.  The idea is that as employees submit the form responses of the days work/activities that would drop into a master spreadsheet holding all the responses from the form and then the columns of timestamp, initials, and description of activity will automate into a completely different sheet (not another tabbed sheet in the same spreadsheet) for the clients timesheet and then another separate spreadsheet for the employees timesheet so everything matches across the three documents without having to manually input the same data across three different spreadsheets.  The main spreadsheet also is running other sheet tabs that have auto dating scripts running.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This can be be done by creating a function, triggering it to run by form submission, that appends the selected submitted values to the specified sheets.

Comment: In Google Sheets and Google Apps Script context, the term custom function is used for *user-defined functions* to be used in spreadsheet formulas. This is relevant because using *custom function* as in search queries in the documentation, Stack Overflow, and Web might lead to many unrelated stuff.